# Creating Wowza HTTP Header Custom Module

Tags: java, eclipse, module, wowza

I need to secure Wowza Media Engine server,
Our policy is to prevent and do not left any footprints, like servername and its version on HTTP Response Header:

```
    Server:WowzaStreamingEngine/4.8.5
```

We created this module by Eclipse + Wowza IDE plugin:

```
package mypackage;

import com.wowza.wms.application.*;
import com.wowza.wms.amf.*;
import com.wowza.wms.client.*;
import com.wowza.wms.module.*;
import com.wowza.wms.request.*;
import com.wowza.wms.stream.*;
import com.wowza.wms.rtp.model.*;
import com.wowza.wms.httpstreamer.model.*;
import com.wowza.wms.httpstreamer.cupertinostreaming.httpstreamer.*;
import com.wowza.wms.httpstreamer.smoothstreaming.httpstreamer.*;

public class MyModule extends ModuleBase {
      public void onHTTPSessionCreate(IHTTPStreamerSession httpSession) {
        httpSession.setUserHTTPHeader("Server", "ItsASecret");
      }
}
```

after saving the project, IDE automatically generate mine.jar into [installDIR]/lib folder,
the We add the module to the [installDIR]/conf/vod/Application.xml:

```
<Modules>
    <Module>
        <Name>base</Name>
        <Description>Base</Description>
        <Class>com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleCore</Class>
    </Module>
    <Module>
        <Name>logging</Name>
        <Description>Client Logging</Description>
        <Class>com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleClientLogging</Class>
    </Module>
    <Module>
        <Name>flvplayback</Name>
        <Description>FLVPlayback</Description>
        <Class>com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleFLVPlayback</Class>
    </Module>
    <Module>
        <Name>mypackage</Name>
        <Description>IDK</Description>
        <Class>MyModule</Class>
    </Module>
</Modules>
```

Unfortunately it is not working, is there any mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a module, add a property to your Server.xml file in the `Properties` at the bottom.

```
<Property>
<Name>httpHeaderServer</Name>
<Value>ItsASecret</Value>
<Type>String</Type>
</Property>
```

This will override the value you are looking to hide. Faster and easier to maintain too.